# C++: How to set an iterator to a list inside a struct inside another list

Tags: c++, list, struct, iterator

I'm new to c++ and this is my first post. I have a question regarding lists.

I have a struct:

```
struct record
{
     list<string> courseList;
};
```

There are other things in the list, but they are not pertinent. I also have a list of records

```
list<record> studentList;
```

My question is, how do I set an iterator to courseList.begin()?

I have tried:

```
list<record>::iterator sl; //studentList
list<record>::iterator cl; //courseList

cl = (*sl).courseList.begin();
```

But I get an error "no match for 'operator!='.

Comment: Are you sure your posting is accurate? You've defined `sl` as `list<record>` rather than `list<student>`, is this intentional?

Comment: Also, `sl` is not defined as a pointer-type, so why are you dereferencing it?

Comment: Yes my posting is accurate. sl is an iterator for a list of record structs.

Comment: @Dai, you can dereference iterators.

Comment: @cortcase, but surely `cl` should be `list<string>::iterator`, and you can't dereference `sl` if it doesn't point to anything yet.

Comment: I'm dereferencing it because when I don't I get: "error: 'struct std::_List_iterator<record>' has no member named 'courseList'"

Comment: @JonathanWakely whops, I missed the `::iterator`-part!

Answer (score 0):

```
list<record>::iterator sl; //studentList
```

This is a default constructed iterator, meaning it doesn't refer to anything yet and so is not dereferenceable, and you can only use it in very limited ways.

```
list<record>::iterator cl; //courseList
```

This is also a default-constructed iterator, and if it's meant to refer into a courselist then it has the wrong type, it should be `list<string>::iterator`.

```
cl = (*sl).courseList.begin();
```

This tries to dereference the non-dereferenceable iterator (which is very bad, your program will crash *if you're lucky*. If you're unlucky it will do something worse).

If the iterator actually was dereferenceable then the result of the expression would be a `list<string>::iterator`, which can't be assigned to `cl` because that is a different type.

You probably want something like this:

```
list<record>::iterator sl = studentList.begin();
if (sl != studentlist.end())
{
    list<record>::iterator cl = (*sl).courseList.begin();
    if (cl != sl->courselist.end())
    {
        // do stuff with the iterator
    }
}
```

The initializer for `cl` can also be written like this , which is equivalent and probably more conventional:

```
    list<record>::iterator cl = sl->courseList.begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been answered. Amature mistake, I made cl a list::iterator instead of list. Thank you everyone

Answer (score -1):

you should use 2D vector for this:

```
vector < vector<string> >ele(10);
```

Then insert elements like this:

```
ele.at(0).push_back("abc");
ele.at(0).push_back("def");
```

And to use iterators

```
ele.at(0).begin();
ele.at(0).end();
```